# Can I put "well" before the main verb?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I've read the rule which states:

> One ought to put an adverb of manner after the main verb if the verb
>   is intransitive, but if there's a direct object after the main verb
>   and the verb is transitive you can put that adverb either in front of
>   the main verb or after the direct object.

Following that rule, I've made up these sentences with the adverb of manner "well":

1) I sing songs well. / I well sing songs.

2) I play football well / I well play football.

But I'm not sure if they're all actually correct. Could you explain the right rule to me?

Comment: Generally, it is only some (not all) of the -_ly_ adverbs that can occur between subject 
 and lexical verb: "I definitely sing songs" / "I happily play football".

Comment: Interesting. Are there any exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

The second form is not natural in any standard English, as far as I am aware. I can't give you a rule: I don't think there is one. But *well* is not used before the verb in that way. This also applies to *badly*. I'm think some other adverbs also don't work there, but I'm not sure which.

Comment: What about this sentence?

"Josh badly needs to buy a new pair of jeans." The adverb of manner "badly" is placed in front of the main verb "need".

Comment: @Rusletov: You're right. _Badly_ can go before _need_ and _want_. But it can't go before _sing_. Note that its meaning is bleached in those cases: it doesn't mean "in a bad way", it is an intensifier. _Seriously_ and _desperately_ can be used in the same way, again as intensifiers. But _well_ can't be used in those cases. (In some varieties of current British speech _well_ is used as an intensifier before adjectives, though not before verbs AFAIK.)

Comment: Child: la-la-la. Fond father: that was well sung!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey. Mebbe. I'm inclined to think that _sung_ is an adjective there, rather than verb.